# Strange problem in threads, application doesn't exit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

OK I'm writing a Zoom component and I wanted it to capture from screen within a secondary thread.
You can pretend I just want to derive TThread in an empty component. I didn't write any codes in the thread so it is just a simple useless thread. I wrote this code: `Thrd := TCaptureThread.Create(False);` in the component main class.
Then I wrote `Thrd.Free` in the main class destruction code. Now when I close the whole application, although it destroys everything, the process doesn't terminate completely. In Windows Task Manager shows that number of threads is 1 but the process remains. If I comment the thread creation line, everything becomes OK and application terminates quickly. What am I gonna do about this? :(

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could show us the code for starters

Comment: Try setting FreeOnTerminate to true, then on main class destruction, set Terminate to true

Comment: @LeleDumbo That won't help. You'd need to wait on the thread. OP is, apparently, already doing so with `Thrd.Free`.

Comment: You're right David. I'm doing it with `thrd.free` however I tried `FreeOnTerminate` and it didn't help! First please tell me, does using threads in components cause problems all the time or just in my component it happened?

Comment: please don't make us guess. Show us code. But VCL components and threads mix like oil and water.

Comment: FreeOnTerminate just calls Free when the thread terminates but that's somewhat pointless since you already call Free. You should ignore that suggestion.

Comment: If you dont want to terminate you thread in the brute way, you should ask it to die nicely, and to make asking work, you should make your thread to listen to that. Usually done in the form of: `while not Terminated do ThreadStuff();`

Comment: oh no. I'm totally sad. I found out that in a new application it works but in my application it doesn't. I'm disappointed. It is a commercial software so I can't upload the whole source. It's already 20 thousand lines. Why is this happening? Please tell me all possible causes :(

Comment: @user we can't tell you all possible causes. What you need to do is to debug the code and find out what's going on.

Comment: @David: I'll try to make this problem happen in a sample application similar to mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `Thrd.Free` the following code from `TThread.Destroy` is run:

```
Terminate;
if FCreateSuspended then
  Resume;
WaitFor;
```

Calling `Free` on a thread will thus terminate the thread synchronously.

My guess is that the call to `WaitFor` never returns. Perhaps `TCaptureThread.Execute` doesn't check `Terminated` and exit. Perhaps `TCaptureThread` is waiting on the main thread and so the wait on the thread deadlocks.

It's pretty hard to do anything other than guess, based on your question, but I'd want to check whether or not your code gets past the `WaitFor` call in the destruction of `Thrd`.  Enable Debug DCUs, set a breakpoint one the call to `WaitFor` and see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

That can be SO many thing... From the `Execute` method of your thread never exiting to a deadlock.

First thing you should do to try to diagnose is run your application under Delphi. Then, since you say it's at the closing of the application it hangs, you close the application.  Now that your application hanged, you pause the application and check the Thread debug panel.  There, click on each thread to check their callstack. That should give a better idea of why it hangs, and exactly which thread hangs.

Answer (score -2):

Write your thread on this way:

```
type
  TCaptureThread = class(TThread)
  private
    //
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: False);
  end;

implementation

constructor TCaptureThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  // Set FreeOnTerminate to True
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TCaptureThread.Execute;
begin
  // Write the Execute method here...
  // And don't forget to synchronise with the form
end;

end.
```

In the form, instantiate your thread

```
Thrd := TCaptureThread.Create(False);
```

Execute it

```
Thrd.Execute;
```

And terminate your thread

```
Thrd.Terminate;
```

I've been using threads on this way for a while, and I never had problems.

Comment: How will this help? I don't see you waiting on the thread. OP already said that `Free` is called which terminates and then waits until thread is signaled.

Comment: calling Thrd.Execute will not run a thread, it will execute the code in the main thread instead.