# How to free a thread in delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I have multithreaded application as I ask [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575590/why-terminated-property-of-thread-is-set).
I want to terminate the thread, and start a new one when following method is called.

```
procedure TFRABData.RefreshDataset;
var
  GridUpdater: TGridUpdater;
begin
  if Assigned(updaterThread) and (updaterThread <> nil) then
  begin
    updaterThread.Terminate;
  end;
  GridUpdater := TGridUpdater.Create(True);
  GridUpdater.OwnerForm := Self;
  updaterThread := GridUpdater;
  GridUpdater.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  GridUpdater.Start;
  CodeSite.Send('RefreshDataset executed');
end
```

but, when `FreeOnTerminate` set to `True`, I get Access Violation, but when `FreeOnTerminate` set to `False`, I get memory leak. How to free the thread?

Comment: So you want to have one and only one this type of worker thread running at one time ? In other words, when the `RefreshDataset` method is called, you want to terminate the currently running thread - interrupt its currently performed operation and let's say (re)start it ? If so, then I would keep one, still running (just pending) thread.

Comment: But, when `RefreshDataset` is called, it means something changed, and it need to re-run the thread from beginning even when current worker thread is not finish yet.

Comment: Looking at what's inside (from your previous question), it will be better to create more than one thread. You have there some stored procedure loading and that is probably time consuming and it might take some time before you'd be able to *restart* the thread (you'd have to wait until the current operation finishes). No, that's not a good idea, taking back...

Comment: You must never hold a reference to an executing thread for which you have set FreeOnTerminate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

And in addition to [RRUZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12577099/757830), to let it work with `FreeOnTerminate = False`:

`Terminate` just sets the flag, it does nothing more.

Change

```
  if Assigned(updaterThread) and (updaterThread <> nil) then 
  begin 
    updaterThread.Terminate; 
  end;
```

to

```
  if Assigned(updaterThread) then 
  begin 
    updaterThread.Free; 
  end;
```

`Free` will call `Terminate` and `WaitFor` subsequently to eliminate your memory leak.

Comment: It's working by combine @RRuz and @ngln's answer. Avoid to create suspended thread and calling `free`, not `terminate`

Comment: I just realize, to terminate current thread, it must wait the stored proc to finish executing, and it still take some time and make UI freeze.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You could ask a new question on how to prevent thát.

Comment: @NGLN, you can prevent it simply; don't call `Free` but `Terminate` :-) When you call `Free` on thread, the caller is waiting for the thread to terminate and that may take some time if you're in the middle of some long running operation. +1ed anyway...

Comment: -1 NEVER call `Free()` on a thread that has not been signaled to terminate yet. DO NOT rely on the thread destructor calling `Terminate()` and `WaitFor()` for you. ALWAYS call them explicitally in your own code instead. Plenty of people have run into problems over the years by freeing a running thread and letting the destructor do the termination. It just does not work correctly, and is not the right place to handle this anyway.

Comment: @Remy That's really confusing. I used to use [all three of them](http://www.nldelphi.com/Forum/showthread.php?p=216573#post216573), but I switched to make use of only `Free` as suggested [here at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6637794/757830) (among _many_ others). I think we really should have faith in the VCL code. But I agree with you that this is not the best solution for OP _in this situation_. I just wanted to point out the `FreeOnTerminate = False` possibility.

Comment: It has been proven time and time and time again that the `TThread` destructor **CANNOT** be relied on to properly terminate the thread if it is still running. What David and you are suggesting is **dangerous**.  DO NOT rely on it.  Explicitally terminate a thread yourself, **THEN** free it.

Answer (score 11):

You need to call `Terminate()`, `WaitFor()` and `Free()` all together, eg:

```
procedure TFRABData.RefreshDataset; 
var 
  GridUpdater: TGridUpdater; 
begin 
  if Assigned(updaterThread) then 
  begin 
    updaterThread.Terminate; 
    updaterThread.WaitFor; 
    FreeAndNil(updaterThread); 
  end; 
  GridUpdater := TGridUpdater.Create(True); 
  GridUpdater.OwnerForm := Self; 
  GridUpdater.Start; 
  updaterThread := GridUpdater; 
  CodeSite.Send('RefreshDataset executed'); 
end;
```

Comment: In this case, when OP wants to have a grid updated as soon as possible I wouldn't wait for the thread to terminate. I would prefer to use `FreeOnTerminate` and just terminate the thread and create another one. Surely, you'd have to be very careful, when synchronizing the UI thread, since there's a big race condition risk from the ghost threads and the updates can't be frequent due to ghost thread count. Both might be solved by organizing all threads to a collection with a certain limit of ghosts count. With the model, that OP currently has might be probably easier to (re)use just one thread.

Comment: The thread is using a database connection and posting UI updates.  If you just signal the existing thread to terminate without actually waiting for it, the new thread might trample on that.

Answer (score 6):

1. avoid the need of start a suspended thread
2. modify your `TThread` constructor to receive the OwnerForm parameter
3. set the FreeOnTerminate value in the constructor of your thread.
4. Start the TThread in a not suspended state.

something like so.

```
  TGridUpdater = class(TThread)
  private
    FOwnerForm: TForm;
  public
    constructor Create(OwnerForm : TForm); overload;
    destructor Destroy; override;
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

constructor TGridUpdater.Create(OwnerForm: TForm);
begin
  inherited Create(False);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
  FOwnerForm:=OwnerForm;
end;

destructor TGridUpdater.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TGridUpdater.Execute;
begin
  //your code goes here

end;
```

Now you can create your Tthread on this way

```
GridUpdater:=TGridUpdater.Create(Self); //Just set it and forget it
```

Comment: It's working, but, when `RefreshDataset` is called again when thread is not finished executing yet, it still throw Access violation

Comment: Try the @NGLN recommendations.