# How to destroy/free an anonymousThread

Tags: delphi, automatic-ref-counting, firemonkey

On windows, to stop and destroy an anonymous thread, i simply do **FmyTask.free** => that will call **destroy** => and that inside the destroy will set **terminate = true** and call **waitfor** to wait the task is finished => and finally clean the memory used

but on ARC, everything is different :(
i use this code :

```
TMyObject
private
  FMyTask: TThread;
public
  destructor Destroy; override;
  procedure DoSomething; 
end;

destructor TMyObject.Destroy;
begin
  FMyTask.free;  // << will do nothing because FMyTask.refcount = 2 !! how it's possible ?
  FMyTask:= nil;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMyObject.DoSomething;
begin

  FMyTask:= Thread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      sleep(10000000);
    end);
  FMyTask.FreeOnTerminate := False;
  FMyTask.Start;

end;
```

and i do nothing else than just

```
MyObject := TmyObject.create;
MyObject.DoSomething;
MyObject.free;
MyObject := nil;
```

but as you see, in the onDestroy of TmyObject, FMyTask have a refcount of 2 !! so it's mean that the FMyTask will be not destroyed (refcount will be decreased to 1) with TmyObject (but later) and you imagine all the bug that can results :(

it's sean that a reference to fMyTask is keep inside this function :

```
function ThreadProc(const Thread: TThread): Integer;
var
  FreeThread: Boolean;
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  pool: Pointer;
{$ENDIF MACOS}
begin
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
  Thread.__ObjAddRef; // this ensures the instance remains for as long as the thread is running
{$ENDIF}
  TThread.FCurrentThread := Thread;
{$IF Defined(POSIX)}
  if Thread.FSuspended then
    pthread_mutex_lock(Thread.FCreateSuspendedMutex);
{$ENDIF POSIX}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
  // Register the auto release pool
  pool := objc_msgSend(objc_msgSend(objc_getClass('NSAutoreleasePool'),
                                    sel_getUid('alloc')), sel_getUid('init'));
{$ENDIF MACOS}
  try
    Thread.FStarted := True;
    if not Thread.Terminated then
    try
      Thread.Execute;
    except
      Thread.FFatalException := AcquireExceptionObject;
    end;
  finally
    Result := Thread.FReturnValue;
    FreeThread := Thread.FFreeOnTerminate;
    Thread.DoTerminate;
    Thread.FFinished := True;
    SignalSyncEvent;
    if FreeThread then
    begin
      Thread.DisposeOf;
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
      Thread.__ObjRelease; // This will clear the thread reference that was added by setting FreeOnTerminate.
{$ENDIF}
    end;
{$IFDEF AUTOREFCOUNT}
    Thread.__ObjRelease; // This will clear the thread reference we added above. This may initiate disposal.
{$ENDIF}
{$IFDEF USE_LIBICU}
    // Destroy Collator Cache
    ClearCollatorCache;
{$ENDIF}
{$IF Defined(MSWINDOWS)}
    EndThread(Result);
{$ELSEIF Defined(POSIX)}
{$IFDEF MACOS}
    // Last thing to do in thread is to drain the pool
    objc_msgSend(pool, sel_getUid('drain'));
{$ENDIF MACOS}
{$IFDEF ANDROID}
    // Detach the NativeActivity virtual machine to ensure the proper relase of JNI context attached to the current thread
    PJavaVM(System.JavaMachine)^.DetachCurrentThread(PJavaVM(System.JavaMachine));
{$ENDIF ANDROID}
    // Directly call pthread_exit since EndThread will detach the thread causing
    // the pthread_join in TThread.WaitFor to fail.  Also, make sure the EndThreadProc
    // is called just like EndThread would do. EndThreadProc should not return
    // and call pthread_exit itself.
    if Assigned(EndThreadProc) then
      EndThreadProc(Result);
    pthread_exit(Result);
{$ENDIF POSIX}
  end;
end;
```

is it a normal behavior ? if yes, i m the only one to think that arc is the worse think of delphi ?

Comment: The anonymous thread should check `Terminated` regularly. And when destroying the object, call `FMyTask.Terminate; FMyTask.WaitFor; FMyTask.Free;` That should ensure that the thread has stopped its execution, and it will be freed when arc finds it suitable.

Comment: thank LU, but you didn't understand my problem, i don't care of what is it  doing inside the onexecute, i care that when i do FmyTask.free and fMyTask := nil then FmyTask will actually be not destroyed and this is a radical different behavior than on windows/non arc

Comment: I think I understood. But ARC will take care of freeing the anonymous thread. Have you done a leak test?

Comment: @LURD I used to call precisely those 3 lines in a row, until someone here on SO insisted to not use `WaitFor` because `TThread.Destroy` already calls it.

Comment: yes sure arc will take care of freeing the anonymous thread, but this is where the problem is, because the anonymous thread play with members/fields of TmyObject  (not in my simplistic exemple but in real life), and if tMyObject is already free then problem ... :( of course their is many way to correct this, BUT i just want to point that code who work perfectly on windows (non arc) will not work at all on ARC :(

Comment: @JerryDodge, I know, but there is a long history of implementation details that got it wrong in different delphi versions. See the comment by RemyLebeau here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12577266/576719.

Comment: @loki, the thread stops playing with TMyObject as soon as `FMyTask.WaitFor` is done. Nothing at all to worry about.

Comment: @LU RD: thanks again! and yes, in the destroy of TmyObject i need to add fMyTask.waitFor; this is real different behavior than on windows/non Arc where i simply need to call fMyTask.free :( it's a pity :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ARC must keep an extra reference to the thread in order not free it too soon if the creator should go out of scope.

Under non-ARC, when you call `FMyThread.Free`, the `Destroy` destructor is called and subsequently `Terminate;` and `WaitFor;`

With ARC, calling `Free` decrements ref count and checks for zero. Since there is still one reference left, the destructor is not called.

This means that the pattern to free a thread (with `FreeOnTerminate=false`) should be:

```
fMyThread.Terminate;
fMyThread.WaitFor;  // Wait for the thread to finish
fMyThread.Free;
```

This means that the extra reference taken by ARC is removed and the thread object will be released any time after the creator goes out of scope.

---

Note that this pattern for freeing a thread (with `FreeOnTerminate=false`) works in all compilers, and also avoids rare race conditions when terminating threads in non-ARC land.

---

General rule for all threads that are set to `FreeOnTerminate = true` is they should not be accessed from outside by reference.

Comment: Except that `CreateAnonymousThread` uses `FreeOnTerminate=True` which is not safe to use with `WaitFor` or `Free`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, yes `FreeOnTerminate` is true by default for anonymous threads but in this case it is set to false before execution.